# plz fix this code

Tags: solidity

```
// Fix the errors in this code . 

pragma solidity ^0.4.0;


contract exercise {

   uint public balance;
   string  name= "Sara"
 int[] public nums=[1,2,3];

   function setBalance(int x) public {
       balance = x;
   }

   function getBalance() public  returns (uint) {
       return balance;
   }


   function doubleBalance() public view returns (uint) {
       balance=2*balance;
       return balance;
   }


}
```

Comment: Please have a look to this post before posting questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and also this https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic. You have to describe your issue in detail and it should be usable also by other people. Your question is too ad hoc. 

BTW you forgot a semicolon after `string name= "Sara";`

Answer (score 2):

You had quite a few basic mistakes. I shall point them out. You can use [remix compiler](http://remix.ethereum.org) to find these issues.

- Missing ; after line `string name= "Sara"`
- Assigning Int to uint in then line `balance = x;`
- `getBalance` function is not modifying state and hence should be view
- `doubleBalance` function is marked constant but is modifying state, either mark it view or don't cvaluevalaue of balance in this fn.

The code could be re-written as:

```
// Fix the errors in this code .

pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract exercise {

uint public balance; 
string name= "Sara" ;
int[] public nums=[1,2,3];

function setBalance(uint x) public { 
    balance = x; 

}

function getBalance() public view returns (uint) {
    return balance;
}

function doubleBalance() public view returns (uint) { 
    return 2*balance; 

}

}
```

Comment: You're not providing any explanation about what was wrong and what did you change. Yes, the original question wasn't the best one either but in my opinion it doesn't justify this.

Comment: Yes, I know. I didn't had enough time to explain. But thought atleat working code will help the OP to move forward. I will soon edit the answer with explanations on what OP was doing wrong.